# De-authenticating Wi-Fi without turning off the device

Tags: networking, dhcp, hostapd

I have established Wi-Fi access point using hostapd and the IP address is configured via DHCP.

This is my configuration file

**hostpad.conf**

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=User
hw_mode=g
channel=6
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_passphrase=secretcode
wpa=2
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

**dhcpd.conf**

ddns-update-style none;
ignore client-updates;
authoritative;
option local-wpad code 252 = text;

```
subnet
10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
# --- default gateway
option routers
10.0.0.1;
# --- Netmask
option subnet-mask
255.255.255.0;
# --- Broadcast Address
option broadcast-address
10.0.0.255;
# --- Domain name servers, tells the clients which DNS servers to use.
option domain-name-servers
10.0.0.1, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
option time-offset
0;
range 10.0.0.3 10.0.0.13;
default-lease-time 1209600;
max-lease-time 1814400;
}
```

Now I would like to send a de-authentication message to the device without turning off Wi-Fi.

One possible option is to change the SSID/password in the hostapd.conf file. But changing the configuration file in running state can create some trouble. Is there some other way to send de-authentication message without turning off the Wi-Fi access point

Comment: The [wpa_supplicant api](https://w1.fi/wpa_supplicant/devel/ctrl_iface_page.html) seems to offer a reassociate option.. the actual demon doesn't have as much to offer.

Comment: you could always send spoofed disassociate packets too with the right tools and drivers. When cracking WPA it's the initial associate packets that a cracker wants for the attack so you don't really want a lot of them on the network.